# `do-release-upgrade` from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS fails with Press x to destroy or r to resurrect window

Tags: 16.04, do-release-upgrade

I have one machine running 16.04 LTS. I am trying to `do-release-upgrade` and the upgrade always fails. At the end I get:

> "Press x to destroy or r to resurrect window"

I am searching for a clue as to what might be the problem. 
/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log

`# cat ./main.log
2019-04-16 17:29:25,723 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.xenial']'
2019-04-16 17:29:25,723 INFO uname information: 'Linux romulus 4.4.0-145-generic #171-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 26 12:43:40 UTC 2019 x86_64'
2019-04-16 17:29:26,162 INFO apt version: '1.2.31'
2019-04-16 17:29:26,163 INFO python version: '3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
2019-04-16 17:29:26,167 INFO release-upgrader version '18.04.29' started
2019-04-16 17:29:26,181 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2019-04-16 17:29:26,257 DEBUG screen returned: 'There is a screen on:
        4933.ubuntu-release-upgrade-screen-window       (04/16/2019 02:10:26 PM)(Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.
'
2019-04-16 17:29:26,258 INFO found active screen session, re-attaching`

Comment: Before this line you have mentioned, is there any reason mentioned for the upgrade failure? You can also see if there is anything in the folder `/var/log/dist-upgrade`.

Comment: The file /var/log/dist-upgrade/mail.log

Comment: What about the message(s) before this error line. If possible try to paste the (at least last few) relevant lines from the log.

Comment: see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2416694 for more information
What log are you referring to? None of the logs seem to have any relevant information. I posted the whole main.log above.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out some of the python packages were somehow corrupted. Reinstall the basic Python packages and the ones related to upgrades and package management eventually solved the problem.